# connected subsets of $\mathbb{Z}.$

Tags: general-topology

Determine all the connected subsets of $\mathbb{Z}.$?

I thinks $\mathbb{N} $ will  be the all connected subset of $\mathbb{Z}.$

I'm right or wrong

Comment: Under what topology?

Comment: @Randall usual topology

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are all of the connected subsets of $\mathbb{Q},\Bbb Z$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120842/what-are-all-of-the-connected-subsets-of-mathbbq)

Comment: In this case that typically means discrete, in which case this is trivial.

Comment: That duplicate post doesn't say anything about $\mathbb Z$, even in its title....

Comment: @MatthewDaly well, instead of saying singletons in $\Bbb Q$, the answer now says singletons in $\Bbb Z$. Note $\Bbb N$ is not connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every singleton $\{x\}$ in every discrete space (in particular $\Bbb Z$ with its usual topology) is both open and closed. Hence the component of connectedness of $x$ is $\{x\}$.